Upgrading to Magento 2.4.7-p1
I have magento community 2.4.4-p2. I would like to upgrade to the latest version i think is 2.4.7-p1.
I did this :
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 --no-update
composer update -W

and I get this error:
Problem 1
    - laminas/laminas-log[2.15.0, ..., 2.17.0] require psr/log ^1.1.2 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: psr/log[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4, 2.0.0, 3.0.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 requires psr/log ^2 || ^3 -> satisfiable by psr/log[2.0.0, 3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install psr/log 3.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p1].
    - Root composer.json requires laminas/laminas-log ^2.15 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-log[2.15.0, ..., 2.17.0].

If doesnt make any sense i mean magento 2.4.7-p1 requieres psr/log v2 or v3 and laminaslog cant work with those versions and its also required.
Please any help,
Thanks

The issue you're encountering is a version conflict between psr/log required by laminas/laminas-log and magento/product-community-edition. Specifically, laminas/laminas-log requires psr/log version 1.1.x, while Magento 2.4.7-p1 requires psr/log version 2.x or 3.x.
To resolve this conflict, you have a few options:

Upgrade laminas/laminas-log (if possible):
Check if there's a newer version of laminas/laminas-log that supports psr/log version 2 or 3. If such a version exists, you can require that version in your composer.json.

Use a compatibility bridge:
If no compatible version exists, you might consider using a compatibility bridge or an alternative logging package that works with the required psr/log versions.

Custom Resolution:
Manually configure the versions in your composer.json to force the compatibility. However, this is not recommended as it might lead to other issues and instability.


Here is how you might handle this in your composer.json:
Step-by-Step Resolution

Check for compatible versions:
First, check if there's a newer version of laminas/laminas-log that is compatible with psr/log 2 or 3:
composer show laminas/laminas-log --all | grep versions

If you find a compatible version, update your composer.json accordingly:
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",
    "laminas/laminas-log": "compatible-version-here"
}


Force the PSR/Log Version:
If there are no compatible versions of laminas/laminas-log, you may attempt to force the psr/log version in your composer.json:
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",
    "laminas/laminas-log": "^2.15",
    "psr/log": "^2.0.0"
},
"provide": {
    "psr/log": "2.0.0"
}

This step forces the psr/log version to 2.0.0 which might resolve the conflict. Note that this is a workaround and could lead to potential issues if the laminas/laminas-log package does not fully support the psr/log 2.x version.

Run Composer Update:
After making the changes to your composer.json, run the update command again:
composer update -W



Final composer.json Example
Here's an example of how your composer.json might look:
{
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",
        "laminas/laminas-log": "^2.15",
        "psr/log": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "provide": {
        "psr/log": "2.0.0"
    }
}

If this approach does not resolve the issue, you may need to reach out to the maintainers of the involved packages or seek further assistance from the Magento community or forums, as they might have specific recommendations for resolving such conflicts.


Install or Update laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin: composer require laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin

Run Composer Update: composer update


Magento Update Commands:
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer self-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento maintenance:disable


Ohh this answer was also very good

laminas log is not needed, just remove it.
composer remove laminas/laminas-log

